# Showing Expired Entries in Channel Entries Edit List

Tags: control-panel

So our client is constantly adding entries that have expiration dates, but in the Edit page for Channel Entries, you can't filter the list to show all expired entries for example.

Problem is that the client then has no idea which entries have expired and which haven't.

Any ideas on how to approach this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Zenbu add-on](https://zenbustudio.com/software/zenbu) - it will allow you to filter and sort by any field. No way to do this otherwise without hacking core files I'm afraid.